# UISearchBar No Background Landscape Mode

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have the following snippet to remove the background from a UISearchBar:

```
for (UIView *subview in self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.subviews) 
{
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) 
    {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
        break;
    }
}
```

However, if the device is rotated to landscape a black background appears behind the search bar. Any ideas how to fix it? I'm not exactly sure if this is undocumented.

Thanks!

Comment: Try this: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/9063557/384864](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9063557/384864)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just ran across this problem and found little help searching. Unfortunately, removing the feature was not an option so I had to figure it out. It seems as the the UISearchBar view has a background that goes black when you change orientation. So my code now looks like this:

```
[searchBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
for (UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews)
{
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")])
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: do you have any idea why this works? why should a backgroundColor of `[UIColor clearColor]` work any differently than one of `nil`?

Answer (score 0):

Given the undocumented nature, I removed the feature. Appears to be a bug due to the undocumented call.

Answer (score 0):

got it ....

open the interface builder under searchbar attributes in view, Mode is set as 'Redraw' set it to scaleToFill