# UISearchBar remove background on iOS 4.1

Tags: iphone, ios4, uisearchbar

I'm trying to remove the background of UISearchBar to make it transparent. I tried these solutions:

1.

```
for (UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews) {
if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
    break;
}
}
```

2.

```
[[searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
```

These two methods both work on iOS 4.3, but not on 4.1. it shows black. How can I make it work on iOS 4.1? I'm using SDK 4.3. Thanks.

Comment: if you are making a new app then it's not required to test your app in 4.1 because as appstore guideline now onwards you have to submit app which compitable with sdk from 4.3 to 6.0.

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
[[searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
[searchBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this is what i was looking for. Though removing from superview works, i have noticed if i have resized the uisearchbar, it tends to have a black background, setting the searchbar's background color to clear color worked. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @AdamCarter: It's not good practice. There should be property for this. But until Apple implements it this is the only way to remove background.